# How to point spring-cloud-config server to a git folder inside a git repo

Tags: git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Please help me to resole the following problem.I would like to have a folder for each micro service in git repo. Please refer the sample structure I have inside git repo. https://github.com/tech-vishesh/config-server_properties

```
If we have same properties under different folder
        like
        ms-one
        |--- application.properties
        |--- application-prod.properties
        |--- application-dev.properties
        ms-two
        |--- application.properties
        |--- application-prod.properties
        |--- application-dev.properties

        we have define search path in spring cloud config bootstrap file
        spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=ms-one,ms-two
        Now we have to load profile in client application then how we can load the profile?
        I have define
        spring.application.name=application
        spring.profiles.active=dev
        but how to define which folder.

    Current spring boot version 2.2.5
```

Comment: Hi @CoreThought  I am facing same issue did u found any solution?

Answer (score 7):

It can be solved. The trick is to give search-path `{application}` without quotes as given below.
It was a little tricky as spring documentation mentions it as '{application}' , probably spring developers just wanted to highlight it with quotes.

In spring cloud server add below mentioned search path-

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths={application}
```

instead of

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'
```

This sets the search path(on server side) equal to the name of client application name  .

now if your microservices/applications- they should have spring.application.name as below-

```
spring.application.name=ms-one
```

and

```
spring.application.name=ms-two
```

they would be looking at the properties file within their respective folders of ms-one and ms-two.

Comment: life saver answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to set next property for **Spring Cloud Config Server**:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'
```

in this case your client application name will be used as a search path for the folder.

Comment: Here is my config server configuration - server.port: 7070
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/tech-vishesh/config-server_properties
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir = D:\\git_backup
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=false
spring.profiles.active=dev
logging.level.root=DEBUG

Comment: Here is my microservice configuration -spring.application.name=DEPARTMENT_SERVICE
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:7070
#spring.cloud.config.label=master
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
spring.profiles.active=dev
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=DEPARTMENT_SERVICE

Comment: @CoreThought your git configuration repo differs from the one you stated in the question. Add new folder DEPARTMENT_SERVICE (= your application name, like ms_one in the question), and there pls add application-dev.properties.

Comment: I did as you have said but it's unable to resolve the properties.

Comment: could you please help me to achieve this scenario

Comment: @CoreThought yes, please. config-client: bootstrap.properties -> spring.application.name=DEPARTMENT_SERVICE  spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888; config-server: application.properties -> spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/nazar-mykolyshyn/test-config spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'. test config dir structure -> test-config/DEPARTMENT_SERVICE/application-dev.properties

Comment: Sorry but still not working. Let me upload my project on git hub then you can try.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Point to your git repo and set the subfolder in the `searchPaths`

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/sarat9/config-server-spring-boot
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=config-repo
```