# Fetching properties from spring cloud config repo with sub folders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to have a folder structure for my config repo.

```
root
├── serviceA
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   └── application-prod.properties
├── serviceB
│   ├── application-dev.properties
│   └── application-prod.properties
```

In my config server I have the following in my `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        monitor:
          github:
            enabled: true
          gitee:
            enabled: true
        git:
          password: ${PASSWORD}
          username: ${USERNAME}
          uri: ${LINK_TO_CONFIG}
          default-label: master
          search-paths: serviceA, serviceB
```

When running the server and requesting `http://localhost:8081/serviceA/prod` or `http://localhost:8081/serviceB/prod` I get the same result

```
{
   "name":"serviceA",
   "profiles":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":"9df32c9dbd11be65e892caf878ddc8d16906a849",
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"GITHUB_URI/springcloudconfigrepo/serviceB/application-prod.properties",
         "source":{
            "profile":"some-service-prod"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"GITHUB_URI//springcloudconfigrepo/serviceA/application-prod.properties",
         "source":{
            "profile":"another-service-prod"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My question is, how can I fetch properties of serviceA only (or serviceB)?

My spring cloud config server on github is [here](https://github.com/Ali-Wassouf/springcloudconfigserver)

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500158/how-to-point-spring-cloud-config-server-to-a-git-folder-inside-a-git-repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the configuration for `searchPaths` as you application name.

The configuration should looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ${LINK_TO_CONFIG}
          searchPaths: '{application}'
```

Comment: If more info is needed about this solution you can find more info in the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_placeholders_in_git_uri

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `search-paths` , need to have property files names as below :

```
root
├── serviceA
│   ├── serviceA-dev.properties
│   └── serviceA-prod.properties
├── serviceB
│   ├── serviceB-dev.properties
│   └── serviceB-prod.properties
```